# Form Array Duplicate Validation

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating project using angular. In my project i have added form array. I need to add validation to check duplicate value validations.

```
this.testForm.controls.forEach((item, index) => {
        
        item.get('position').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
          let duplicateValue = this.checkDuplicateValues(item,value);
          if(duplicateValue == "isExist"){
            item.get("position").setErrors({'incorrect': true});
          }
})

checkDuplicateValues(item,value){
    let fieldName = item.value.fieldName
    if(value){
      for(var i=0; i<this.testForm.value.length; i++){
        if(this.testForm.value[i].fieldName != fieldName){
          if(this.testForm.value[i].position == value){
            
            return "isExist"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

}

This logic is not working properly. This is not validating properly.